# Visual Studio 17.8 now generates warning C5271 from marshal.h header

Tags: visual-studio, c++-cli, visual-studio-2022

I just updated to the Visual Studio 17.8 release.  All of a sudden, My C++/CLI DLL generates a warning

```
16>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\include\msclr\marshal.h(19,12): warning C5271: consider replacing #using <system.dll>  with command line argument /FU "C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\7.0.14\ref\net7.0\system.dll"
```

The issue occurs in the standard `<marshal.h>` header file because it has this bit near the top

```
// #using is not used in the Windows build.
#if !defined _CRT_WINDOWS && !defined UNDOCKED_WINDOWS_UCRT
    #using <system.dll>
#endif
```

The project in question is a C++/CLI DLL.  it uses the V143 toolset and uses the `/std:c++17` flag.  It enabled .NET Runtime support (`/clr:netcore`) and has a target framework of net7.0-windows.

I am not sure what to do about this.  Obviously, I can silence the warning, but I would prefer to address what's causing it.  What changed exactly?  Should my DLL somehow be defining `_CRT_WINDOWS` when it is not?  Is there some other change I should be making?

Comment: Well, the compiler changed.  Looks to me the team wants to eventually deprecate #using, sensible thing to do given the gawdawful compile command lines in .netcore projects.  There's no easy fix for you until they figure out what to do with marshal.h, that could take a while.  Move on and disable the warning.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a new warning to VS (I think it is, but could be wrong)... But MS does add new warnings every now and again that their own code does not conform to. I tend to just put in a pragma suppress, or similar, in these cases until MS gets around to fixing it. You could also report the issue to MS on the VS feedback website.

Comment: I noticed a [similar report](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/92879) on GitHub.